# How to validate functions in hardhat test

Tags: solidity, web3js, hardhat, chai

Actually i am validating an function to check that only whitelisted members or owner can access this function but when i am running this test file i am getting reverting error that
**Error**

```
Validations
         should revert error for non whitelisted memeber:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Only owner or whiteListed members allowed'
    at KeyboardNFT.isWhiteListedorOwner (contracts/nft_erc721.sol:1102)
```

**Code**

```
describe("Validations", function () {
    it("should revert error for non whitelisted memeber", async function () {
      const {hardhatToken, owner, addr1, addr2} = await loadFixture(deployTokenFixture);
      expect(await hardhatToken.connect(addr1).awardItem(addr1.address,"first nft")).to.throw("Only owner or whiteListed members allowed");
    });
  });
```

Comment: Pro tip: see my [hardhat-template](https://github.com/paulrberg/hardhat-template).

You will probably not bump into this error.

Comment: thx @PaulRazvanBerg for suggestion i solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

`.to.throw ...`

to

`.to.be.revertedWith(<revertMessage>)`

Example :
`await expect(Contract.add()).to.be.revertedWith("Only owner or whiteListed members allowed");`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sola24 but i want to edit it a bit, well you answer is correct but instead of adding await inside except i put it outside then it worked. but it does not work when it put that await inside expect.

Comment: ah yes. that too. I didn't see that